# No configured handlers in Symfony Messenger

Tags: php, symfony, queue, handler, messenger

I'd like to implement Messenger async handlers and be able to queue some tasks in Redis, but I can't for some reason.

**Here is my global config :**

- PHP 7.3.16
- Symfony 4.4.7
- Messenger 4.4
- Redis 5.0.3
- Predis 1.1

**I tried to follow this guide :**

https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/messenger.html

Everything is a copy/paste from the doc, except that I replaced my controller with a command.

This dispatch command seems to work :

`php bin/console app:dispatch-command`

> ^ Symfony\Component\Messenger\Envelope^ {#5465   -stamps: []
>   -message: App\Message\SmsNotification^ {#5475
>       -content: "Look! I created a message!"   } }

**This command returns no configured handlers :**

`php bin/console debug:messenger`

> Messenger
>
> =========

**This second command returns an error while trying to consume a message**

`php bin/console messenger:consume async`

```
TypeError {#174
      #message: "The first argument must be an instance of "Symfony\Component\Messenger\RoutableMessageBus"."
      #code: 0
      #file: "./vendor/symfony/messenger/Command/ConsumeMessagesCommand.php"
      #line: 54
      trace: {
        ./vendor/symfony/messenger/Command/ConsumeMessagesCommand.php:54 { …}
        ./var/cache/dev/ContainerM8fc2IB/srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php:3736 {
          ContainerM8fc2IB\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer->getConsole_Command_MessengerConsumeMessagesService()^
          › 
          › $this->privates['console.command.messenger_consume_messages'] = $instance = new \Symfony\Component\Messenger\Command\ConsumeMessagesCommand('', ($this->privates['messenger.receiver_locator'] ?? ($this->privates['messenger.receiver_locator'] = new \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Argument\ServiceLocator($this->getService, [], []))), ($this->services['event_dispatcher'] ?? $this->getEventDispatcherService()), ($this->privates['monolog.logger.messenger'] ?? $this->getMonolog_Logger_MessengerService()), []);
          › 
          arguments: {
            $routableBus: ""
            $receiverLocator: Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Argument\ServiceLocator {#178 …}
            $eventDispatcher: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher {#188 …}
            $logger: Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger {#179 …}
            $receiverNames: []
          }
        }
        ./vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Container.php:450 { …}
        ./vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Argument/ServiceLocator.php:40 { …}
        ./vendor/symfony/console/CommandLoader/ContainerCommandLoader.php:45 { …}
        ./vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:541 { …}
        ./vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:634 { …}
        ./vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php:117 { …}
        ./vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:235 { …}
        ./vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php:83 { …}
        ./vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:147 { …}
        ./bin/console:42 { …}
      }
    }
    2020-04-20T20:08:02+02:00 [critical] Uncaught Error: The first argument must be an instance of "Symfony\Component\Messenger\RoutableMessageBus".
```

**Here are some relevant files...**

```
# .env
MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=redis://127.0.0.1:6379/messages/?auto_setup=true&serializer=1&stream_max_entries=0&dbindex=0
```

```
# config/packages/messenger.yaml
framework:
    messenger:
        transports:
            async: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
        routing:
            'App\Message\SmsNotification': async
```

```
# config/services.yaml
parameters:

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

```
<?php
// src/Message/SmsNotification.php

namespace App\Message;

class SmsNotification
{
    private $content;

    public function __construct(string $content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;
    }

    public function getContent(): string
    {
        return $this->content;
    }
}
```

```
<?php
// src/MessageHandler/SmsNotificationHandler.php

namespace App\MessageHandler;

use App\Message\SmsNotification;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Handler\MessageHandlerInterface;

class SmsNotificationHandler implements MessageHandlerInterface
{
    public function __invoke(SmsNotification $message)
    {
        dump('ok!');
        echo('handler');
    }
}
```

```
<?php
// src/Command/DispatchCommand

namespace App\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle;
use App\Message\SmsNotification;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\MessageBusInterface;

class DispatchCommand extends Command
{
    protected $bus;
    protected static $defaultName = 'app:dispatch-command';

    public function __construct(MessageBusInterface $bus)
    {
        $this->bus = $bus;
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setDescription('Dispatch test command')
            ->setHelp('Dispatch test command');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $dispatch = $this->bus->dispatch(new SmsNotification('Look! I created a message!'));
        dump($dispatch);
    }
```

Can someone please help me?

Cheers!

**Update**

I tried to manually route my handlers as explained in [the doc](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/messenger.html#messenger-handler-config) :

```
# config/services.yaml
App\MessageHandler\SmsNotificationHandler:
    tags: [messenger.message_handler]
```

But it changes nothing.

I also checked if my message and message Handler were registered as services, and it is :

```
php bin/console debug:container App
```

> [70 ] App\Message\SmsNotification
>
> [71 ] App\MessageHandler\SmsNotificationHandler

Comment: Did you check without async message, by commenting routing option in config?

Comment: Yes I tried, but it changes nothing. I also tried to manually configure handlers like this  https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/messenger.html#messenger-handler-config and it changes nothing either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what causes this issue, but I just succeeded to resolve it by installing a whole new Symfony 4.4.7 project and by overwriting it.

I also figured out that swiftmailer was replaced by mailer, and twig-bundle by twig-pack, but only for new projects, without beeing notice by composer for existing installations (even using composer update/upgrade/recipes. It may be the cause of my problems but I'm not sure.

**Step 1 : create a new Symfony 4.4.7 project**

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton newProj ^4.4.7
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data 
cd /newProj
```

**Step 2 : overwrite with my git project**

```
git init
git remote add origin $url_of_clone_source
git fetch origin
git checkout -b master --track origin/master
```

**Step 3 : install vendors and replace obsolete dependencies**

```
composer install
composer remove symfony/swiftmailer
composer require symfony/mailer
composer remove symfony/twig-bundle
composer require symfony/twig-pack
```

**Step 4 : check messenger**

```
$ php bin/console debug:messenger

Messenger
=========

messenger.bus.default
---------------------

 The following messages can be dispatched:

 ---------------------------------------------------------- 
  App\Message\SmsNotification                               
      handled by App\MessageHandler\SmsNotificationHandler  
  Symfony\Component\Mailer\Messenger\SendEmailMessage       
      handled by mailer.messenger.message_handler           
 ----------------------------------------------------------
```

**Here is my actual composer.json file**

```
{
  "type": "project",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "require": {
    "php": "7.3.*",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.5",
    "impulze/intervention-image-bundle": "^1.2",
    "laminas/laminas-code": "^3.4",
    "laminas/laminas-eventmanager": "^3.2",
    "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^3.6",
    "predis/predis": "^1.1",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
    "symfony/asset": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/console": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/error-handler": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/expression-language": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
    "symfony/form": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/http-client": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/intl": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/mailer": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/messenger": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/orm-pack": "*",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^5.0",
    "symfony/process": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
    "symfony/translation": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/twig-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/validator": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/web-link": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.7",
    "symfony/yaml": "4.4.*"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.3",
    "sensiolabs/security-checker": "^6.0",
    "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
    "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
    "symfony/test-pack": "*"
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": {
      "*": "dist"
    },
    "sort-packages": true
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "replace": {
    "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
    "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
      "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
      "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd",
      "security-checker security:check": "script"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "@auto-scripts"
    ]
  },
  "conflict": {
    "symfony/symfony": "*"
  },
  "extra": {
    "symfony": {
      "allow-contrib": false,
      "require": "4.4.*"
    }
  }
}
```